# Yahoo Multiplayer Games: What is the reason to have multiple rooms for a game?

Tags: multithreading, sockets

Yahoo has multiple rooms for a game. For example, let's choose Chess. 
For Chess, they have multiple rooms, and every rooms has multiple tables.

What would be the reason to have multiple rooms ?
Will the server be slower with 1 room and 10.000 tables than 10 rooms and 1000 tables for each room ?

If yes, please make me understand why. I know they use Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

'The' server would probably run the same with 1 room. What makes you assume that every room runs on the same server? Usually splitting up a service is done as a simple way of spreading load between multiple boxes.

Comment: yes, they can host each room on separate server. this can be the reason but is not proven. i have talked with another developer and he has 6 games and 2 games per server, each game having 5 rooms

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that choosing a "room" from a list of 10000 tables would prove to be a poor user experience, and reduces the amount of data sent back to the client during room selection.

Comment: so, you practically say that it isn't slower in any case ?

Comment: Without knowing anything of the implementation, it's impossible to do anything other than specualte on their design decisions.